# Entity framework Datetime mapping issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I have the follwing query that works fine

```
     var myList = (from p in db.full
                     where (p.date_reception > new DateTime(2015,01,01) )
                      group p by p.mc_object into g

                     select new StringIntType 
                     {
                         str  = g.key,

                     }).ToList();
```

But when i use this one by defining the dateTime outside the query

```
   DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01);

       var myList = (from p in db.full
                     where (p.date_reception > dt)
                    group p by p.mc_object into g

                     select new StringIntType 
                     {
                         str  = g.key,

                     }).ToList();
```

Query keeps turning till i get the following error `connetion timout expired`

Please i need to know why .

Comment: The second snippet is different and won't compile.

Comment: Does the second snippet really not have the group by, or is that a typo?

Comment: Ooops, yes it has i've edited it

Comment: This is not an EF problem but a query tuning problem. Post the execution plan and script out the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Did either of those code blocks give you the expected results to begin with?

If you group into `g`, then `g` will have a property `Key` for the group, set to the value of the field you grouped by, and you can iterate over the group to get the objects in the group.

So `g.Key` would correspond to the `mc_object` for the group.  Assuming the typos are fixed so the code compiles, this should work...

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01);

var myList = 
    (from p in db.full
     where (p.date_reception > dt)
     group p by p.mc_object into g
     select new StringIntType  
     {
         str  = g.Key, // <- the key is what you grouped by, or mc_object
     }).ToList();

myList.ForEach(s => {
    // do some work with distinct mc_object, s.str
});
```

The result of this would be a `List<StringIntType>`, containing a list of all distinct `mc_object` values with `date_reception > dt`.  I have mocked this up and tested with both a nullable and non-nullable date field.

Also, this assumes `StringIntType.str` is of the same type as `mc_object` *or* there is an implicit conversion between the two.

---

You might actually want to iterate through the groups.  Something like...

```
var myList = (from p in db.full
               where (p.date_reception > dt)
               group p by p.mc_object into g
               //order by g.Key // optionally order them by the key
               select g); 

myList.ForEach(g => {
    // g.Key == distinct mc_object value for the group

    g.ForEach(i => {
        // i.mc_object will be the same for all i in this g            
        // do some work on an individual DB record, i.mc_object            
    });
});
```

or...

```
var myList = (from p in JobBO.GetJobCycles(92291, 92291)
              where (p.DateRevised > dt)
              group p by p.mc_object into g
              from q in g
              select new StringIntType {
                  str = q.mc_object, // same for all in a particular group
                  otherProp = q.other_val // distinct DB row ID for example
              }).ToList();

myList.ForEach(i => {
    // do some work on an individual DB record, i.str
});
```